# How do I apply an annotation to all Grafana dashboards?

Tags: grafana

I want to add a new annotation query to every dashboard. Is there a way to do this without just manually doing it 1 by 1 for each individual dashboard?

The example we want to add is to include the GitHub Releases for our GitHub repo to each graph so we can see the effect of releases on metrics. We're using the GitHub plugin for this.

Is there a way to do this en-masse?

Answer (score 0):

The team at Grafana said there currently is not a way to do this automatically or via the UI.

Their recommendation would be to write a script which uses the Grafana API to add the annotations:

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/annotations/

I've not attempted this, but it might be beneficial to others.

We did it manually instead.